# Spring Batch - How to access JobParameters or JobExecution for a dynamically created Job?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a dynamically created/configured  list of ReportJobs which are implemented as standard spring batch job instances. These jobs are executed by the Spring Task Scheduler

```
@Override
public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
    taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());

    // create report jobs
    for (Map.Entry<String, ReportConfiguration> entry : jobsConfiguration.getReports().entrySet()) {
        final ReportConfiguration reportConfiguration = entry.getValue();
        final Job reportJob = createReportJob(entry.getKey(), reportConfiguration);

        CronTask ct = new CronTask(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addDate("started", new Date())
                    .toJobParameters();

                try {
                    jobLauncher.run(reportJob, jobParameters);
                } catch (JobExecutionException e) {
                    LOG.warn("cannot execute reportJob");
                }
             }
        }, reportConfiguration.getCron());

        taskRegistrar.addCronTask(ct);
    }
}
```

As you see, these jobs are not spring beans, they are created on the fly. Is it possible to access JobParameters etc. during execution of the ItemWriter or the Job processor?

Answer (score 0):

If you know name of job, you can use retrieve jobInstance using [JobExplorer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/index.html?org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html) and from JobInstance using same [JobExplorer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/index.html?org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html) you can retrieve JobExecutions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to access JobParameters etc. during execution of the ItemWriter or the Job processor?

Yes, you can save the step execution in your processor/writer with a `@BeforeStep` callback, then you can get access job parameters from the `StepExecution`. Here is an example:

```
public class MyItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Object> {
   private StepExecution stepExecution;

   public void write(List<? extends Object> items) throws Exception {
      JobParameters jobParameters = this.stepExecution.getJobParameters();
      // use job parameters
   }

   @BeforeStep
   public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
      this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
   }

}
```

Hope this helps.